# Extracting data from a command response and store it in a variable

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I would like to disable my touchpad during startup process with a script like this

`#!/bin/bash`

```
# determine device id
ID=$(xinput list | grep -i touchpad)

# check output
echo $ID

# disable device identified by $ID
#xinput set-prop $ID "Device Enabled" 0</code>
```

Basically I would like to extract "12" (or whatever number the device has) from the result of command:

- xinput list | grep -i touchpad
  ⎜ ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=**12** [slave pointer (2)]

and store it in variable $ID.

The next command would disable the device.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

Thanks, Udo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the output of `xinput list` will always have the ID number as the 5th field then use:

```
ID=$(xinput list | awk -F'[= ]' '/TouchPad/{print $5}')
```

If you'd rather key off of the word `id=` such that it can be anywhere on the line then use:

```
ID=$(xinput list | sed '/TouchPad/s/^.*id=\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/')
```

Comment: xinput list | awk -F'[= ]' '/TouchPad/{print $5}' outputs SynPS/2 -> changing the parameter does not give me 12... The 2nd command works after a minor edit ;)

Comment: @udo I was rejecting your edit, but meanwhile someone else approved it. It's better to edit your question with the code you finally used than to modify/edit an answer.

Comment: @belisarius: probably SiegeX approved it. without this edit the code was not working.

Answer (score 1):

GNU `grep`:

```
ID=$(xinput list | grep -Poi '(?<=touchpad[[:blank:]]*id=)[0-9]+')
```

GNU `sed`:

```
ID=$(xinput list | sed -n 's/.*touchpad[[:blank:]]*id=\([0-9]\+\)[[:blank:]]*.*/\1/Ip')
```

Comment: @udo: `echo 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=12 [slave pointer (2)]' | grep -Poi '(?<=touchpad id=)[0-9]+'` and `echo 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=12 [slave pointer (2)]' | sed -n 's/.*touchpad id=\([0-9]\+\) .*/\1/Ip'` both give me "12".

Comment: yep, confirmed. but when I use xinput list | grep -Poi '(?<=touchpad id=)[0-9]+' I get nothing... not sure where the problem is...

Comment: @udo: I just checked and `xinput` outputs tabs. I've changed my answer to reflect that.